# How to tune a certain segment of the auc in binary classification (using mlr)?

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, auc, mlr

I would like to optimize a certain segment of the ROC curve and therefore only a partial AUC in the tuning process. Is that available in the mlr package, is there another measure suitable for that aim or do I have to create a new measure object. If the latter is true, how could I do it?

Example with normal AUC as measure:

```
library(mlr)
Species = sample(c("yes","no"), size=150, replace=T)
data_binom = data.frame(x1=(Species=="yes")+rnorm(150,1,4), 
                        x2=(Species=="no")+rnorm(150,0,9), Species)
learner = makeLearner("classif.rpart", predict.type = "prob")
task = makeClassifTask(data=data_binom, target="Species", 
                       positive="yes")
task = subsetTask(task, subset=sample(1:150, size=100))
param = makeParamSet(makeNumericParam("cp", lower=0.00001, upper=.1))
control = makeTuneControlGrid(resolution=10L)
tuneParams(learner=learner, task=task, resampling=cv10, measures=auc, 
           par.set=param, control = control)
```

Comment: Two-Way Partial AUC is a new interesting tool that should answer your question: https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.00298 . It is implemented in the `tpAUC` package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tpAUC/index.html

Comment: I think it's not yet included but following the tutorial http://mlr-org.github.io/mlr-tutorial/devel/html/create_measure/index.html on how to create your own measure it should be simple. You can also probably take the AUC implementation as an example: https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr/blob/90f7422c6493e42b26d4d61602b394301ad56f49/R/measures.R#L793-L825